# Array values to be displayed just like spread sheet values in JSF (inserting vertical lines in between array values in jsf)

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am getting array values from

```
<td>
    <ui:repeat var="test" value="#{mybean.valuesToDisply}">
<td>

<h:outputText value= "#{test}">
</h:outputText>

</td>
</ui:repeat>
</td>
```

but this is printing `123456` . I want this to print as we have columns and horizontal line in spread sheet . (like in the table ,each test value to be in each column so that it looks like a table having vertical and horizontal values).

I tried searching in google about inserting spaces but i am using richesFaces 4 and it does not support richspaces tag , it does support primeSpacer tag but I don't want to use prime faces. Please help me in solving this to display it as excel spread or inserting spaces at least between array values so that it looks neat and clear in web page.

Comment: If you need space, then use `h:graphicImage`, for example `<h:graphicImage value="/images/spacer.gif" width="5" height="5" />`. If you need columns, then use `rich:dataTable`.

Comment: You are nesting a td in a td... Won't work. First td probalby needs to be a tr

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I solved it by using <h:outputText value= "#{test}  &#160; &#160; &#160; "> . Yes  you are right first td is tr.